# IONIC Framework (AngularJs & JavaScript) | is SOAP based web-service recommended?

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, ionic-framework

I am going to use SOAP based web-service for one of my project. (IONIC framework is based on AngularJS and they have written SOAP client in JavaScript)

My Question are:

1. Is SOAP based web-services recommended using javascript?
2. Will there be any performance issue ?
3. What type/kind of issues, i will face during development?

thanks,
Aleem

Answer (score 2):

SOAP is not recommended because it's XML based.

REST is a recommended approach because it is usually based on JSON, which is a native JavaScript format.

With SOAP you will incur overhead of constant JSON / XML conversion.

Here is a comparison: http://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest

Answer (score 1):

> Is SOAP based web-services recommended using javascript?

It depends on your application you are working on. If you want security in 
your application like your are build app for payment system or something then SOAP will be recommended. But you need to compromise in performance. You can also add security by using Oauth or any third party library.

> Will there be any performance issue ?

Yes if you compare SOAP performance with Rest then SOAP load time is more than rest api. Because in SOAP we first load xml of service then hit exact function.

> What type/kind of issues, i will face during development?

I think you can do whatever you want with SOAP.